# BIRT, how to get the length of the report parameter?

Tags: java, reporting, birt

I have been trying to make a list box report parameter with multiple choice enabled. I'm trying to filter my report based on this parameter. I have wrote a code something like this, but it is not working;

```
importPackage(Packages.java.util.logging);
var fileHandler = new FileHandler("/tmp/birt.log", true);
var rootLogger = Logger.getLogger("");
rootLogger.addHandler(fileHandler);

var queryString = "";
queryString = "select * from public.r_"+params["rid"]+"_0 where (r_date_1 >= '"+params["startdate"]+"' and r_date_2 <'"+params["enddate"]+"')";
queryString += " and (r_vchar_3=";

filterIPLength = reportContext.getParameterValue("filterIP").length;
Logger.getAnonymousLogger().info("Parameter Count: "+filterIPLength);


for(i = 0; i<filterIPLength; i++) {
    queryString  += "'"+reportContext.getParameterValue("filterIP")[i]+"'";

    if (i != filterIPLength - 1) {
        queryString += "or r_vchar_3=";
    }
}

queryString += ")";
this.queryText = queryString;
```

the problem here is, `reportContext.getParameterValue("filterIP").length;` line always returns 1, even though I choose multiple parameters and the report only shows the first selected data since for loop runs only once.

What may cause this problem? How can i debug and solve it?

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: What about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402148/how-do-i-set-a-parameter-to-a-list-of-values-in-a-birt-report ?

Comment: I have different question. I've already used multiple values enabled list box parameter, and bind it to my sql query. my question is getting the count of the selected values, it always returns 1 even if i choose 5-6 value from list, as i told before.

Comment: Which event script is this code in? It may make a difference.

Comment: hi Mark, it's in BeforeOpen event on my data set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script should work, at least it works in my BIRT version (2.6, Eclipse 3.6, Win-32). I've written a small minimalistic report (which works) to track down the problem, probably it can help you debugging.:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/birt/2005/design" version="3.2.22" id="1">
    <property name="createdBy">Eclipse BIRT Designer Version 2.6.1.v20100902 Build &lt;2.6.1.v20100915-1750></property>
    <property name="units">in</property>
    <property name="iconFile">/templates/blank_report.gif</property>
    <property name="bidiLayoutOrientation">ltr</property>
    <property name="imageDPI">120</property>
    <parameters>
        <scalar-parameter name="NewParameter" id="7">
            <property name="valueType">static</property>
            <property name="dataType">string</property>
            <property name="distinct">true</property>
            <list-property name="selectionList">
                <structure>
                    <property name="value">123</property>
                    <property name="label">test</property>
                </structure>
                <structure>
                    <property name="value">124</property>
                    <property name="label">test2</property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <property name="paramType">multi-value</property>
            <property name="controlType">list-box</property>
            <property name="mustMatch">true</property>
            <property name="fixedOrder">true</property>
            <structure name="format">
                <property name="category">Unformatted</property>
            </structure>
        </scalar-parameter>
    </parameters>
    <data-sources>
        <script-data-source name="Data Source" id="95">
            <method name="beforeOpen"><![CDATA[paramLength = reportContext.getParameterValue("NewParameter").length;]]></method>
        </script-data-source>
    </data-sources>
    <data-sets>
        <script-data-set name="Data Set" id="96">
            <list-property name="resultSetHints">
                <structure>
                    <property name="position">0</property>
                    <property name="name">test</property>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <list-property name="columnHints">
                <structure>
                    <property name="columnName">test</property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <structure name="cachedMetaData">
                <list-property name="resultSet">
                    <structure>
                        <property name="position">1</property>
                        <property name="name">test</property>
                        <property name="dataType">string</property>
                    </structure>
                </list-property>
            </structure>
            <property name="dataSource">Data Source</property>
        </script-data-set>
    </data-sets>
    <styles>
        <style name="report" id="4">
            <property name="fontFamily">sans-serif</property>
            <property name="fontSize">10pt</property>
        </style>
        <style name="crosstab-cell" id="5">
            <property name="borderBottomColor">#CCCCCC</property>
            <property name="borderBottomStyle">solid</property>
            <property name="borderBottomWidth">1pt</property>
            <property name="borderLeftColor">#CCCCCC</property>
            <property name="borderLeftStyle">solid</property>
            <property name="borderLeftWidth">1pt</property>
            <property name="borderRightColor">#CCCCCC</property>
            <property name="borderRightStyle">solid</property>
            <property name="borderRightWidth">1pt</property>
            <property name="borderTopColor">#CCCCCC</property>
            <property name="borderTopStyle">solid</property>
            <property name="borderTopWidth">1pt</property>
        </style>
        <style name="crosstab" id="6">
            <property name="borderBottomColor">#CCCCCC</property>
            <property name="borderBottomStyle">solid</property>
            <property name="borderBottomWidth">1pt</property>
            <property name="borderLeftColor">#CCCCCC</property>
            <property name="borderLeftStyle">solid</property>
            <property name="borderLeftWidth">1pt</property>
            <property name="borderRightColor">#CCCCCC</property>
            <property name="borderRightStyle">solid</property>
            <property name="borderRightWidth">1pt</property>
            <property name="borderTopColor">#CCCCCC</property>
            <property name="borderTopStyle">solid</property>
            <property name="borderTopWidth">1pt</property>
        </style>
    </styles>
    <page-setup>
        <simple-master-page name="Simple MasterPage" id="2">
            <page-footer>
                <text id="3">
                    <property name="contentType">html</property>
                    <text-property name="content"><![CDATA[<value-of>new Date()</value-of>]]></text-property>
                </text>
            </page-footer>
        </simple-master-page>
    </page-setup>
    <body>
        <data id="107">
            <property name="whiteSpace">nowrap</property>
            <property name="dataSet">Data Set</property>
            <list-property name="boundDataColumns">
                <structure>
                    <property name="name">test</property>
                    <text-property name="displayName">test</text-property>
                    <expression name="expression" type="javascript">dataSetRow["test"]</expression>
                    <property name="dataType">string</property>
                </structure>
            </list-property>
            <property name="resultSetColumn">test</property>
        </data>
        <text-data id="93">
            <expression name="valueExpr">"Param length is " + paramLength</expression>
            <property name="contentType">html</property>
        </text-data>
    </body>
</report>`

Comment: stranger thing; my code works if i run it on my computer, but if i send it to server it is not working. so i guess there is something wrong with birt engine on server that cause a problem and "reportContext.getParameterValue("filterIP")" function is not working as expected. :/