# BIRT Before Open value list params errors

Tags: birt

I have a (semi) basic data cube set up with a cascading parameters of State and Area. The state select box is straight forward as is the Area; when a user selects a State, the Area options are set accordingly. However, the value for Area is a long list of strings that will be sent to the mysql select statement which will use both params (State & the list of strings from Area) several time. Its a big ugly collection of UNIONS. My problem is somewhere between the before Start and query time.

```
//beforeOpen script...LState & LAreas the name of the report param
this.queryText = this.queryText.replace('stateList', params["LStates"].value);
this.queryText = this.queryText.replace('areaList', params["LAreas"].value);


In my mysql statement I use them in the following way:
SELECT ..XXX..
FROM ..XXX..
WHERE ..XXX..
State.State_Location in ('stateList')
AND Range_Locator.Range in ('areaList')
UNION ALL
SELECT ..XXX..
FROM ..XXX..
WHERE ..XXX..
State.State_Location in ('stateList')
AND Range_Locator.Range in ('areaList')
```

The two errors I get from BIRT are:

(Pretty obvious)

- Cannot get the result set. org.eclipse....SQL statement doesn ot return a ResultSet object.

(Not so obvious to me)

- A BIRT exception occured. Error evaluating Javascript expression. Script engine error: Can't find method java.lang.String.replace(string.java.lang.Object[]).
  There are error evaluating script "this.queryText = this.queryText.replace('stateList', params["LStates"].value);this.queryText = this.queryText.replace('areaList', params["LAreas"].value);"

Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

It seems LStates is defined as a "multi-value" parameter, therefore params["LStates"].value returns an array of values: this is why this replace method does not work.

You should try like this:

```
this.queryText = this.queryText.replace('stateList', params["LStates"].value.join("','"));
```

Comment: That saved me: join(" ',' "));

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what you are doing in beforeOpen script, but your SQL is looking for the string values 'stateList' & 'areaList' and is probably not happy about the ().  You need to use question marks to call the parameters you define in the 'parameters' you set up in the data set design.

```
SELECT ..XXX..
FROM ..XXX..
WHERE ..XXX..
State.State_Location in ?
AND Range_Locator.Range in ?
UNION ALL
SELECT ..XXX..
FROM ..XXX..
WHERE ..XXX..
State.State_Location in ?
AND Range_Locator.Range in ?
```

I don't recall using

```
 in ?
```

In any queries, I usually try and set it to use

```
like ?
```

There are number of issues in sending multiple choice parameters to SQL via BIRT.  you might want to look at [How do I set a parameter to a list of values in a BIRT report?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402148/how-do-i-set-a-parameter-to-a-list-of-values-in-a-birt-report) There are also some security concerns.  When I have to filter on multiples, I usually do it in a filter (data set design option) after the SQL has run. Thought this can be a resource problem if your SQL returns lots of values.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies but since I was unable to get these options to work, I wound up restructuring the database & sql statements to run better. To address some previous suggestions:

@dom the states parameter has only one value and while using "IN ('stateList')" is not efficient (disclaimer, not my code) adding the .join(',') did throw an error specific to that; I tried and mysql/BIRT seemed to be expecting a comma separated list but got a string with a trailing comma.

@James I tried using the question mark (?) instead of the 'stateList' & 'areaList' but I think mysql/BIRT was not able to recognize which value went with which question mark...not too sure though since I was not able to debug well enough and find out exactly why. Could be a form to param mapping issue that I didn't notice. Thanks for the help.