# SQL statement at Birt Report for parameters

Tags: birt

Currently I'm using Birt Report to generate report from my system. I'm using input parameter to send parameter from my system to Birt Report. The problem is when I'm trying to send multiple parameter from my system.

SQL statement at Birt Report for one parameter

```
select actualdate from table1 where storeloc = ?;
```

When I use this query for one parameter, it work.

I tried sql like this

```
select actualdate from table1 where storeloc = params["storeloc"].value;
```

I already created parameter at data set and report parameter but it's still can't gets to work

and also birt dont show me the options in edit dataset   for query    and     Linked To Report Parameters  in parameters

so what should i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set a parameter to a list of values in a BIRT report?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402148/how-do-i-set-a-parameter-to-a-list-of-values-in-a-birt-report)

Answer (score 1):

Create a parameter storeloc in report params section of Data source.
Write this query in dataset open:

```
select actualdate from table1 where storeloc='"+params["storeloc"]+"';
```

Fetch the actualdate value in data source fetch and run the report.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In future, please *edit* your answer to make corrections, rather than posting another answer.