# How to Pass multiple values to SQL query of IN operator through BIRT REPORT params?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, birt

If I pass one value it is working fine, When I try to send multiple values to IN operator I am not getting data.

[image]

When I send single value **ACCEPTED** it is working, When I send like below manner it is not working.
i tried in multiple ways like below :

```
ACCEPTED','DATADIFF
'ACCEPTED','DATADIFF'
"ACCEPTED','DATADIFF"
```

How can I send multiple values to in operator?(and a.ReasonCode in (?))

Comment: What are the queries being sent?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402148/how-do-i-set-a-parameter-to-a-list-of-values-in-a-birt-report) and [this](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/68084/) can help you.

You can try using a SELECT subquery in the field.

Answer (score 0):

well try this image 
[Refer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrMqh.png)

So you can take multiple values by this method

Comment: The answer does not show how to actually *use* the parameter.